# Background c program for keyboard mapping

Tags: c, windows, fonts

I have installed a Bramma TTF file in my windows 8 system. Through a windows character map, I was able to find individual character code. Attached below the screenshot of the map. We can see at the right bottom side, the character code for "!" is 0x21. Similarly, I can find all the character code of all other letters.

[image: Character map for Bramma TTF]

Now I defined a character mapping for this font with my US based keyboard layout. For example, I mapped physical character 'a' in the keyboard to the character shown in 3rd row and 1st column. [whenever I hit 'a' from the keyboard, the corresponding character has to be displayed]

I would like to write a background C program such that it listens the keyboard hit and as per my previously defined character mapping, my C program should output that mapped character. i.e., when i hit character 'a' from the keyboard it should return the mapped character.

Can any one help me out in solving this problem or else just give me a lead towards the solution.

Comment: Just to check if I got your problem. You want to have a background program that changes the character output on your console/terminal. So, for example, when using the console in an application, pressing 'a' would draw on screen the mapped character?

Comment: @KuramaYoko Yep. Its exactly what i need.

Comment: This looks like a tricky thing that would involve messing around with the character encoding system. I know my way around linux but windows I can't help much. This [link](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter03) have a little bit of information on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat familiar with these kind of fonts, they popped up in other questions at SO.  The kind of questions from users that tried to deal with the consequences of using such a font.  They are rather grave.

The biggest problem is that this font is not Unicode compatible.  The actual string that underlies the text that's rendered to the screen is very different, containing characters from the ANSI character set.  What goes **horribly** wrong is when the program that displays these strings saves the data.  The data file contains the original strings, a good example is an Excel spreadsheet.  This spreadsheet just contains gibberish when it is read by any other program.  Especially bad when read by a program on another machine that doesn't have the same font installed.  Very, **very** painful.

You are in fact making this problem worse by even destroying the normal mapping between keyboard to ANSI character.  The 1st character in the 3rd row is produced by typing a capital I (eye) on the keyboard.

The message is clear: **don't do this**.  Windows supports Unicode compatible fonts with Indic scripts well, fonts like Sylfaen, Mangal, Latha.  All of which are available on my Windows 8 machine, about ten thousand miles away from where they are normally used.  It also has Indic keyboard layouts available under the Language applet, I just picked one as an example:

[image]

Well, it is your funeral.  You don't have to write a C program to translate these keystrokes, you need a custom keyboard layout.  It is a DLL.  You normally need the DDK to build them, but there is simple tooling available to auto-generate them.  It doesn't get any easier than with MKLC, the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.  Web page and download link [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the real problem which im trying to address is to use that font style in my design work in Adobe Photoshop. In general, the font like bramma, alaipayuthe etc really looks beautiful compared to Latha font.

Comment: Moreover, I tried MKLC and succeeded to somewhat in creating a keyboard layout. Im using that right now. But all i wanted is a near perfect application which can be ported to other system using its exe.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use [autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com/).
With this application, you can listen to a set of keys, & then send a different set of keys.

This can be used as implementation of "autocorrect"

e.g.

```
:*:btw::By the way `
```

will autocorrect `btw` to `By the way`.

autohotkey supports quite complicated scripts, & many scripts are already available online.

On another note, if you only want english keyboard to print malayalam unicode characters, you may also think of a popular software called [baraha](http://www.baraha.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Google's Virtual Keyboard (also works with your physical keyboard)

```
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#virtual_keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tavultesoft.com/ allows you to create keyboards for MSWindows and the web. Over 1000 keyboards are readily provided. There is a developer and a user version. With the developer version you may create installation programs which install fonts, keyboards, keymaps and documentation.